# Concatenating columns when joining in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables:

**Orders**

```
order_id   order_total
----------------------
1          150
2          230
```

**Items**

```
order_id   item_number
-----------------------
1          abc
1          foo
2          123
2          bar
2          test
```

I'd like to join both tables and concatenate the `item_number` column, so the results will looks like this:

```
order_id    order_total    item_number_concat
---------------------------------------------
1           150            abc, foo
2           230            123, bar, test
```

What's a way to do this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? SQL is not intended as a _presentation_ system. What is your presentation layer (e.g. WinForms, Reporting systems, PHP,  ASP.NET, etc) and why can't you do it there instead?

Comment: Also, why on earth are you still running SQL Server 2008 today? Why can't you update to SQL Server 2017 or later? The Express edition is _free!_ (MSSQL 2017 has `CONCAT_WS` which is what you want, btw).